# Add array data in HighChart android

Tags: java, javascript, android, arrays, highcharts

Im having a bit trouble with loading array/data from my android/java code to highchart/html code. It is working fine when I will put the data in static:

```
series: [{
        name:'Fruit',
        data: [{name:"Test 1",y:10},
               {name:"Test 2",y:20},
               {name:"Test 3",y:30},]}]
```

But when I will try to add it from my java code:

```
//graph_webview_test is my webview and add the GraphWebInterface() as javascript
graph_webview_test.addJavascriptInterface(new GraphWebInterface(), "Android");


//a method of GraphWebInterface
@JavascriptInterface
    public String getStringTickets(){
        String temp="";
        for(int x=0;x<graphTicketArrayList.size();x++){
            temp= temp+"{name:"+"\""+graphTicketArrayList.get(x).getLabel()+"\""+",y:"+graphTicketArrayList.get(x).getTotal()+"},";
        }
        return temp;
    }


//i tried to print the result(Sample_graph.html)
console.log(Android.getStringTickets());

result:  "{name:"Test 1",y:10},{name:"Test 2",y:20},{name:"Test 3",y:30}",


and call the method to load data.

series: [{
         name:'Fruit',
         data: [Android.getStringTickets()]
                    }]
```

but the highChart is displaying 0 data and a label (slice)

What is the best approach of loading array in highchart.

Thanks Guys,

Comment: are you supposed to have the trailing comma after your dataset?  normally the last entry of JS data structures doesn' have comma

Comment: Hi Raymond, are you referring to this, series: [{
        name:'Fruit',
        data: [{name:"Test 1",y:10},
               {name:"Test 2",y:20},
               {name:"Test 3",y:30},]}]

I tried this code and it runned normally, so what i did is created a String of array with this format but its not displaying the graph.

Comment: Can you post the java code your using to generate this `series: [{
         name:'Fruit',
         data: [Android.getStringTickets()]
                    }]`

Comment: Hi Raymond, i figured out my error, please check my answer. Thank you for your fast response anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to share our solution. My error was I did not make the String from android/java to object. so we add.

```
var temp=eval('['+Android.getStringTickets()+']');
```

and in adding the data:

```
series: [{
          ame:'Crime',
          data: temp }]
```